# is flutter dio package compatable with flutter 2.0?

Tags: flutter, http, https, dio, flutter2.0

I had got some few problems when I migrated to flutter 2.0, does Dio compactable with flutter 2.0 or any way o resolve range error while using Dio package?.

Answer (score 0):

They are still migrating to null safety, but a [stable version should be out soon](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/1073). But there is already a Prerelease available: https://pub.dev/packages/dio/versions/4.0.0-beta7